# awk with dates before 1970

Tags: bash, date, awk

from https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html 
I understand that `gawk` has only 2 functions to work on date/time
`mktime` and `strftime`.

So, I can parse any date using `mktime` that return a long, so I can make any math op, and so I can format the output desired with `strftime`

This works like a charm for any date after `"1970 01 01 00 00 00"`

Using awk, how can I format dates before 1970 ?

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{t=mktime("1970 01 01 00 00 00"); print t; print strftime("%Y-%m-%d", t) }'
10800
1970-01-01
$ awk 'BEGIN{t=mktime("1960 01 01 00 00 00"); print t; print strftime("%Y-%m-%d", t) }'
-315608400
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=- FNR=1) fatal: strftime: second argument less than 0 or too big for time_t
```

Comment: You have to use a hammer and chisel them into your stone slabs ;-)

Comment: It appears like strftime does not accept a negative value for the timestamp (second) parameter, which represents the number of seconds since 1970 01 01 00 00 00 UTC. Times prior to that would have a negative number of seconds *since* then.

Comment: You can omit the `echo "" |` by using `awk 'BEGIN { ... }`

Comment: Great question. I wonder if there's any time interval you can add on and have the month/day/etc, wrap around? I mean what if you could use `2060` for the year when you want `1960` and then subtract 100 years from the result? I doubt if 100 is the magic number and I've no idea if that approach is possible or not. Interestingly when I tried this with 2060 mktime() in gawk 4.0.2 on Solaris returned `-1` so the end apparently IS nigh (our sell-by-date according to mktime() on Solaris is `2038 01 18`, it returns `-1` for any date after that)

Comment: @EdMorton, there is no need of this, see my answer bellow, the problem is that strftime is avoiding negative values, but it is not a real problem, so, a simple comment solve this. look the thread at: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2015-04/msg00012.html for more details.

Comment: @ton I understand, but IMHO most people would not find editing the gawk source code and recompiling it an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, it's a bug ...

I'm using GNU awk 4.0.2, a litte look at source and seems easy to fix:

```
glaudiston:/sources/gawk-4.0.2$ diff builtin.c.orig builtin.c
1701,1702c1701,1702
<                       if (clock_val < 0)
<                               fatal(_("strftime: second argument less than 0 or too big for time_t"));
---
>                       // if (clock_val < 0)
>                       //      fatal(_("strftime: second argument less than 0 or too big for time_t"));
glaudiston:/sources/gawk-4.0.2$ echo "" | ./gawk '{ts="1969 12 31 23 00 00";format="%Y/%m/%d";tv=mktime(ts);print tv;print strftime(format, tv)}'
7200
1969/12/31
glaudiston:/sources/gawk-4.0.2$ echo "" | ./gawk '{ts="1960 01 01 00 00 00";format="%Y/%m/%d";tv=mktime(ts);print tv;print strftime(format, tv)}'
-315608400
1960/01/01
```

For my purpose it worked, but I'm not sure if it was a good idea. I'll send this to gawk maillist for approval.

Discussion started at:
https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2015-04/msg00012.html

## Solution Update:

The awk dev team has fixed the bug, so just upgrade your awk to a new version:

https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-gawk/2015-04/msg00036.html

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, as you've seen, gawk just can't do this directly. The [gawk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html) says:

> All known POSIX-compliant systems support timestamps from 0 through 2^31 - 1, which is sufficient to represent times through 2038-01-19 03:14:07 UTC. Many systems support a wider range of timestamps, including negative timestamps that represent times before the epoch.

The manual doesn't say what `strftime()` does if given an out-of-range date.

But even on my system, which does behave sensibly for negative `time_t` values, gawk's `strftime()` function doesn't support them (though `mktime()` does), and so can't handle dates before 1970. I consider this to be a bug in gawk.

(My advice would be to use Perl instead of Awk, but that doesn't answer the question you asked.)

In principle, you could reinvent the wheel by re-implementing a function like `strftime()` in awk. But that would be overkill.

If your system has a working GNU coreutils `date` command, you can invoke it from `gawk`. Using your example of Jan 1, 1960:

```
$ cat 1960.awk
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    timestamp = mktime("1960 00 00 00 00 00")
    print "mktime() returned " timestamp

    if (0) {
        # This doesn't work
        s = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", timestamp)
        print "strftime() returned ", s
    }
    else {
        # This works
        "date '+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' -d @" timestamp | getline t
        print "The date command printed \"" t "\""
    }
}
$ ./1960.awk
mktime() returned -318355200
The date command printed "1959-11-30 00:00:00"
$
```

(I gave up on figuring out the sequence of quotes and backslashes needed to do this as a one-liner from a shell prompt.)

This probably makes sense if you have a large existing awk program and you need to add this one feature to it. But if you're not stuck with doing this in awk, you might consider using something else; awk may not be the right tool for what you're trying to accomplish.

Or, if you're really ambitious, you could modify the `gawk` sources to handle this case correctly.

Comment: `mktime` is not the problem, it's working fine. the problem seems to be strftime and use a date is not a option because is too slow and too expensive.
I'll see how to it in perl.

Comment: @ton: You're right. I've updated my answer (and suggested another possible alternative: fixing `gawk` yourself).